# Objective-C : Cannot initialize UIViewController in switch case?

Tags: objective-c

Objective-C question : Cannot initialize UIViewController in switch case?

```
switch(anIntegerIndex) {
  case 1:
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

the above has compile error in the UIViewController line. I'm using iOS 5 SDK + xCode 4.2

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: (And in this case I'll forgive you for not quoting the exact error message since it's likely indecipherable unless you've seen it a few times before.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a common C restriction for `switch` statements --

You cannot declare local variables inside an individual `case` unless you put them inside `{}` brackets.

Simplest thing to do is to put the `UIViewController *vc;` declaration ahead of the `switch` and just put `vc = [[whatever..` inside the `case`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create the object but not initialise it?

Such as

UIViewController *vc = null;

switch(anIntegerIndex) {
  case 1:
    *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

etc etc